# Windows 8 time issue

Tags: windows-8, time

I have a new HP desktop computer with Windows 8 installed into it. (Bought it with it) And I've encountered an issue when trying to set the time. My problem is not setting it, but trying to keep it set at the right time. The time changes when i log off/shutdown my PC. Is this an error for windows 8 or is it my computer?

Comment: Could you specify further? Does the time change when you restart/shutdown or does it happen when you are logged in?

Comment: Please edit this information into the question. There's an [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/546540/edit) link under the post.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what type of time distoration you are experiencing. :-) but some possibilities are:

- Gradual time shift: Inaccurate real time clock on pc. Windows 8
  periodically checks the time over the internet via a time server. You
  can see this setting as the third tab dialog on the clock setting.
  You could change this to update more frequently?
- Completely off when rebooting: Your new machine might have a bad, missing or poorly connected backup battery. You would notice that problem when powering off the machine and powering back on. But since that battery also keeps the bios settings, you would probably get other bootup messages (like "Time not set"). This would be under warranty, but probably easier to just replace yourself.
- Off by exactly 1 or more hours: Your timezone is set incorrectly and when the normal time check happens, its resetting to the alternate time zone. The timezone can be set by clicking on the clock in the toolbar.

Comment: Also check DST settings if appropriate for your TZ (i.e. the **Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time** checkbox).